# HTTPS warning for Sites in Salesforce

Tags: salesforce

I am getting following error on a browser when i open Secure(HTTPS) Site URL for my sandbox org,

*You attempted to reach* **.cs9.force.com, but instead you actually reached a server identifying itself as *.cs9.force.com. This may be caused by a misconfiguration on the server or by something more serious*

The problem arises because i am using ***Sites*** for exposing WS and the HTTPS warning gives error on client side while interacting with WS.

How can i configure my org to resolve HTTPS warning message?

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using sites you are able to use HTTP. There is no way to change the HTTPS Site settings. And there is no way to upload your own SSL-Certificate.

Answer (score 0):

Dont know if your problem is resolved by now or not. But you need to configure your WS to accept wildcard SSL certificates. I am currently facing this issue and following [link](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2511587&stqc=true) may be helpful to you.
I can't use this solution because of shared weblogic server across many applications. If you have found any solution to above, can you please comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16016894/configure-wildcard-ssl-hostnameverifier-in-java).