# Configure wildcard SSL hostnameverifier in java

Tags: java, ssl, salesforce, httpsurlconnection

My question is basically to resolve a SSLException due to use of wildcard certificates in my web service calls. Now before people redirect me to any existing SO questions, please note that I am aware of using/creating a Custom hostnameverifier and setting it in weblogic.

My main problem is that since my application runs on a shared weblogic server, I am not allowed to do any changes to weblogic config.xml file. So, I need to do the host name verifier setting in my java code somehow. I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13470998/ignoring-ssl-validation-in-java/13483271#13483271) question which describes how to write a custom HttpsURLConnection class.

**Question**: Now I don't understand how to call my web service methods (using a custom SoapConnection class) from DataOutputStream's writeBytes method?

Note: 

1. Above linked question is ignoring the SSL validation. I will not do that. I found a [class](http://jandrewthompson.blogspot.in/2010/04/weblogic-and-wildcard-ssl-certificates.html) that allows wildcard certificate host names.

2. I forgot to mention that I am using weblogic 10.3.2.0 which does not allow wildcard certificates by default.

Comment: How do you call your web server?
I use RestTemplate, and I can explain how to do it using RestTemplate. For other ways of creating the HttpsURLConnection, I would need to understand how you create the connection.

Comment: I am using connection class provided by the web service itself. We pass username, password and a hostname to the class. Its via SOAP.

Comment: Usually you need to configure the class which creates the connection with a factory that will build your own custom https connection.

Comment: Have a look at a question I asked not so long ago in which I explained how I built the connection. You need to convert what I did with RestTemplate, to your way of building connections:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15544116/sslhandshakeexception-received-fatal-alert-handshake-failure-when-setting-ciph

Comment: Actuallty, I have seen your post before too. You are modifying server.xml and I cannot modify any weblogic config files.

Comment: That's not the issue here. Look at the java code in which I create a custom HTTP client and modify HttpsURLConnection to use my verifier. You need your own verifier.

Comment: Can you move the discussion to chat? I am getting warning everytime I try to post a comment?

Comment: I understand till the point that we can specify our own verifer class in HTTP client. But again my main question: How do I call web service method after creating the Httpurlconnection?

Comment: I have to admin that I'm not familiar with you're way of doing things so I'm not sure how to further continue from here.